# JavaScript IE double submit with form.submit()

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom-events

I am experiencing difficulties with IE (8, 11) double submit which is triggered by JavaScript code:

```
this.disabled=true; 
form.submit(); 
return false;
```

Sentence `form.submit();` actually triggers 2 threads in jsp. Other browsers Firefox and Chrome work OK and only one thread is triggered. I have to use plain JavaScript and no jQuery.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How is the above code executed? From where?

Comment: can you show your complete html markup for the form, and the javascript?

Comment: Jes when we click on a button problem occurs only in IE.
<input type="button" name="button1"  SIZE="40" value="Confirm" onClick="confirmFunction()">
function confirmFunction { this.disabled=true; form.submit(); return false; }

Comment: <form dir="..." action="/webapp" method="POST" name="SubPage3">

Answer (score 0):

Well you are returning false in the function, but that does nothing when you do not handle it in the click event. You need to add return.

```
<input type="button" name="button1" SIZE="40" value="Confirm" onclick="return confirmFunction()"> 
                                                                       ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thank you for answer.
I corrected it but there are still 2 requests triggered.
I have no idea why this only happens in IE.